# How to place cubes around in a square shape

Tags: modeling

[image]

As it can be seen in the image, I am trying to place all these cubes in such a way that forms a square shape. I don't know how do I place these cubes by evenly spacing out the distance between each cubes. Can somebody please tell me and give me step by step instructions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use ***Dupliverts*** to achieve it.
[image]

In *Edit Mode* add a plane and subdivide it, then delete the faces. In *Object Mode* add a cube and scale it as you like. 
[image]

In Object Mode parent the cube to the plane (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Object*).
[image]

Select the plane and go to the *Object* header-->Duplication panel and push the ***Verts*** button.
[image]

Finally with the plane selected press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to make the duplicates real meshes.
[image]

Comment: I should add that if you want to change the number of splits, you should first delete the edge, connect them with F key and re-devide them with W-S. The number of cuts can be changed in the tool shelf.

Comment: @Allosteric why deleting the edge? Dissolving vertex or vertices should be enough from X > Dissolve Vertices

Comment: I must agree that's a better way.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps me :) But like how would I delete the middle cube then?

Comment: @JoeSmith After making the duplicates real (*Shift+Ctrl+A*) you can easily delete the middle cube.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- Delete all cubes except one;
- Place one cube in a corner;
- Add an Array Modifier to it, set to the correct spacing and cube count;
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to create a duplicate, put it into the next corner, and use <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>90</kbd>,
  <kbd>Enter</kbd> to rotate it 90 degrees;
- Repeat for two more cubes.

If you want you can select all cubes, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open the "Snap" menu, and choose "Selection to Grid". That'll put the cubes at the closest grid intersection point.