# polar array w/empty plane axes

Tags: modifiers

First sorry for my english, i'm trying to create a polar array of a cylinder around another cylinder, i've seen some tutorials about polar arrays using an empty plane axes object to do that, however in my case i cant obtain the result i want, the first image shows the original array of objects, i have a small cylinder on the sufface of the bigger cylinder, i've located an empty plane axes object in the same plane that the small cylinder[image] then i define the array modifier, i want 3 small cylinders around the bigger cylinder, i'm getting 3 cylinders but not around the surface of the bigger cylinder, the first one is the source object, the 2nd is rotated 90º over Z axle, the 3th is rotated 90º respect to the 2nd and around Y axle, [image], i'm guessing that the problem is in the orientation of the axes of the empty plane axes object, can you help me to solve this??? Thanks in advance:
LS

Comment: i want to add, the items are scaled on each item i add to the array...

Comment: From explanation it seems to be unapplied scale on cylinder which is arrayed

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the 3D cursor in the center
2. Add your empty and the cylinder you want to clone
3. Go to edit mode and scale and position your cylinder at the First position
4. back to Object mode and create an array modifier on the small cylinder relative to the Empty and bump count up to 3
5. Rotate the empty 90°

A lot like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94993/47253).